# CoreBluetooth Background Task with Specific Time Interval

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, background-task

I have App which communicate with Bluetooth Device, Fetch data and Display in App.

I am looking to do Same Process when App is in Background. At Every 10 minutes execute one Method which scan Device, Connect with Device, Read Information and then update UI.

- I have enable Background mode "Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories".
- "Info" file exist "App Communicates using Corebluetooth" option.

I have add "applicationDidEnterBackground" Method.It executes upto 3 minutes then it stops.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

NSString* accessToken = [[WSUtils sharedObject] getAccessToken];
if(accessToken != nil)
{
    [[WSBlueToothDevicesViewController sharedObject] registerDeviceSearchTimer];
}

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];

NSLog(@"backgroundTimeRemaining: %.0f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);

}
```

Do anyone have idea how to execute method in background with specific time interval?

Comment: you can use `NSTimer` to schedule task.

Comment: There is no way to schedule a task to execute at specific time intervals while your app is in the background

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have used "NSTimer" but it was not working in Background.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, I tried to find solution, I think you are right but I have not found any documentation from apple which supports this argument.